# Firing dragOver event while using @angular/cdk/drag-drop

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I use `@angular/cdk/drag-drop` module in my app. Dragging and dropping works as expected, but I want to do some actions when drag item is on top of drop area.

I tried this code, but it seems that `onDragOver` method is not called

```
<div cdkDropList>
    <span (dragover)="onDragOver($event)">...</span>
<div>

onDragOver($event){
    console.log('ondragover');
}
```

Is there any built in way in `@angular/cdk/drag-drop` to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation, this is the available events for `CdkDropList`: (All of those events are `output() EventEmitter`)

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDropList

> @Output('**cdkDropListDropped**') dropped -
> *Emits when the user drops an item inside the container.*
>
> @Output('**cdkDropListEntered**') entered -
> *Emits when the user has moved a new drag item into this container*.
>
> @Output('**cdkDropListExited**') exited -
> *Emits when the user removes an item from the container by dragging it
> into another container.*
>
> @Output('**cdkDropListSorted**') sorted -
> *Emits as the user is swapping items while actively dragging.*

Comment: I am trying to achieve an effect where dragging an item over another item will cause the latter's border to become red. But realize that (dragover) seem not to take effect.     
How would the cdk built-in events listed here able to solve the issue? Does that mean (dragover) cannot be used in angular?

Comment: @Bruce - I have the same problem. From what I can see the `cdkDropListEntered` event and `cdkDropListExited` events do not fire at mouseover and mouseout. You would expect the exit event to fire as you leave a list and the enter event to fire as you enter a list. However what actually happens is that they fire simultaneously once you drag an item into a target list - indicating that it's left the first list and on drop will arrive into the second. I don't have a solution yet for your problem tho :(